# Array data split

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I don't know if i am doing the array add by a correct method.

```
for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
                    var a = Array();// loop against the Data array on each object in result
                    var b = Array();
                    a.push(result[i].data.mentionTotal);
                    b.push(result[i].profileName);
                    mentionArr.push(b+a);
                 }
```

The for loop above gave a result like this :

```
[["orange1494"],["ansontest231403"],["happyboy0"],["babygirl0"]]
```

But i want to split the data so i tried to do:

```
mentionArr.push(b+'","'+a);
```

In order to split it but the outcome is like :

```
["orange\",\"1494","ansontest23\",\"1403","happyboy\",\"0","babygirl\",\"0"]
```

Which i am not able to use this array to do my task.

How may i solve it to:

```
[["orange","1494"],["ansontest23","1403"],["happyboy","0"],["babygirl","0"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: 
`for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
        var a = [];
        a.push(result[i].data.mentionTotal);
        a.push(result[i].profileName);
        mentionArr.push(a);
     }`

You dont need to create two arrays. Everytime the for loop runs `a` will initialize as a new array.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to replace one line (`mentionArr.push(b+a);` to `mentionArr.push([b,a]);`) so you generate a new array with a and b in it instead of concatinating the two values:

```
for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
                var a = Array();// loop against the Data array on each object in result
                var b = Array();
                a.push(result[i].data.mentionTotal);
                b.push(result[i].profileName);
                mentionArr.push([b,a]);
             }
```